# PHP multiple image resizing not working

Tags: php

I have a multiple image resizing script.Here is the HTML part

```
<td><input type="file" name="fileUpload[]"><br>
    <input type="file" name="fileUpload[]"><br>
    <input type="file" name="fileUpload[]"><br>
    <input type="file" name="fileUpload[]"><br>
    <input type="file" name="fileUpload[]"><br></td>
```

And here is the php part

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES["fileUpload"]["name"]);$i++)
    {
        if(trim($_FILES["fileUpload"]["tmp_name"][$i]) != "")
        {
            $images = $_FILES["fileUpload"]["tmp_name"][$i];
            $new_images = "thumbnails_".$_FILES["fileUpload"]["name"][$i];
            copy($_FILES["fileUpload"]["tmp_name"][$i],"uploads/".$_FILES["fileUpload"]["name"][$i]);
            $width=100; 
            $size=GetimageSize($images);
            $height=round($width*$size[1]/$size[0]);
            $images_orig = ImageCreateFromJPEG($images);
            $photoX = ImagesX($images_orig);
            $photoY = ImagesY($images_orig);
            $images_fin = ImageCreateTrueColor($width, $height);
            ImageCopyResampled($images_fin, $images_orig, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width+1, $height+1, $photoX, $photoY);
            ImageJPEG($images_fin,"uploads/".$new_images);
            ImageDestroy($images_orig);
            ImageDestroy($images_fin);
```

But its not resizing the images.What can be the reason?
Thanks

Comment: You need to do some debugging. Step through each line of code and see if you're getting the values you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem: `$i<count($_FILES["fileUpload"]["name"])`. `$_FILES["fileUpload"]` is an array of files, each of which has a `name` key.  `$_FILES["fileUpload"]["name"]`, on the other hand, is undefined.  You need to do `` `$i<count($_FILES["fileUpload"]) ``.

Also, as a general rule, don't do this kind of loop:

```
for($i=0; $i<count(...); $i++) {
    ...
}
```

On a small array, that's fine, but with a big array, calculating count() on each loop is a huge hit.  Better to do this:

```
$count = count(...);
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
copy($_FILES["fileUpload"]["tmp_name"][$i],"uploads/".$_FILES["fileUpload"]["name"][$i]);
```

change this to `move_uploaded_file(...);`

Also this is wrong:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES["fileUpload"]["name"]);$i++)
```

change it to:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES["fileUpload"]);$i++)
```